# String matching and replacement in excel

Tags: string, excel

I have two sheets in my excel file. The first one looks like this:

```
**Name** **Code**
Bob      ??
Thomas   ??
Rob      ??
```

The second one looks like this:

```
**Name**  **Code**
Thomas    tom
James     jam
Bob       bob
```

What I want to do is for each name is sheet 1, search in sheet 2 for the correct code and add the code in column two of sheet 1. How would I proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those start at A1 in both sheets, put this formula in `B2` on sheet 1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

This takes the value from `A2`, goes to the range referenced by `A2:B4` on the other sheet (the dollar signs make sure the range doesn't change when you drag/copy the formula), finds the corresponding value and then pulls the value from the column next to it.

Make sure that `Sheet2` actually matches your sheet name. One way to make sure this happens is to start typing the formula and then manually select the range from the table. Once you have selected it, press `F4` to quickly change it to an absolute range (which is what the dollar signs mean).

Comment: Thanks for the VLOOKUP example. Also, I didn't know how to refer to another sheet.

Comment: No problem at all. Anytime you need to reference a range in a formula, you can always select it and make the formula do the hard work for you :) Good luck!